# Problema al instalar CLI y hacer un build en docker

Tags: docker

espero se encuentren muy bien.

Estoy construyendo una imagen de docker con node version 10, pero ocurre un problema cuando ejecuta la linea

```
RUN npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular && \
    ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build -c $ENVIRONMENT --prod
```

**/bin/sh: ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: not found
: exit status 127**

Anteriormente esta funcionando bien, hice una actualizaciones de paquetes y ya no funciona, ya intenté cambiar la forma en la que se instalan y ejecuta la linea éxitosamente pero no funciona como se esperaba.

Agradeceria enormemente que alguien me pudiera orientar. Saludos!

Comment: Donde tienes definido $ENVIRONMENT?.

Comment: se lo paso como argumento al momento de generar la imagen

Comment: Hm. No es evidente que estés corriendo la instrucción desde un directorio con una subcarpeta node_modules.

Comment: Alfabravo implementé este código para separar la instalación y funciona.      RUN npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
RUN npm install @angular/cli build -c $ENVIRONMENT --prod       pero al finalizar su construcción hay una parte del build que no la construye como se esperaba

Comment: Gracias por añadir info relevante a los comentarios. Por favor, procura añadir todos los detalles nuevos en la pregunta, yendo a [edit] que puedes hacerlo cuantas veces lo necesites. Como ves, acá en los comentarios es bien difícil juzgar código o logs.